# Merging multiple multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable number of multidimensional arrays but all with the same 4 possible values for each item.

For example:

```
Array
    (
            [companyid] => 1      
            [employeeid] => 1
            [role] => "Something"
            [name] => "Something"
    )
```

but every array may have a different ammount of items inside it.

I want to turn all the arrays into one single table with lots of rows. I tried array_merge() but I end up with a table with 8, 12, 16... columns instead of more rows.

So... any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding them together with +.  $array = $array + another_array;

Comment: Please can you add some more example arrays. I am not sure what you mean by "different amounts of items inside it". Do you mean sometimes the values are blank? or that you can have multiple groups of 4 values inside a single array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't test it, but you could try the following:

```
$table = array();
$columns = array('companyid' => '', 'employeeid' => '', 'role' => '', 'name' => '');
foreach($array as $item) {
    $table[] = array_merge($columns, $item);
}
```

This should work since the documentation about array_merge say:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one.

So you either get the value of the current item or a default value that you can specify in the `$columns` array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1=Array 
    (
            "companyid" => 1, 
            "employeeid" => 4,
            "role" => "Something",
            "name" => "Something",
    );

$array2=Array 
    (
            "companyid" => array(2,2,2), 
            "employeeid" => 5,
            "role" => "Something2",
            "name" => "Something2"
    );

$array3=Array 
    (
            "companyid" => 3,
            "employeeid" => 6,
            "role" => "Something3",
            "name" => "Something3"
    );
//Using array_merge
$main_array["companyid"]=array_merge((array)$array1["companyid"],(array)$array2["companyid"],(array)$array3["companyid"]);
$main_array["employeeid"]=array_merge((array)$array1["employeeid"],(array)$array2["employeeid"],(array)$array3["employeeid"]);

for($i=0;$i<count($main_array["companyid"]);$i++)
    echo $main_array["companyid"][$i] + "<br />";

for($i=0;$i<count($main_array["employeeid"]);$i++)
    echo $main_array["employeeid"][$i] + "<br />";
```

I've tested the code above and seems right.
You coult also improve this code into a DRY function.